# WordPress calendar plugin with maps

Tags: wordpress, calendar, maps

Is there a way to use a plugin's WordPress to manage calendar events (like Events Calendar or Events Manager..or others) by displaying them on a **custom map**?

I don't want just the Google Maps map offered by default by these plugins, but a map where I can **draw different areas on it**? (as proposed by the *WP Maps Pro* plugin).

Manage events...: https://theeventscalendar.com/

Manage custom drawing maps: https://www.wpmapspro.com/example/show-messages-shapes-google-maps-2/

All the calendar plugins I've seen offer the option of stylizing the Google map (like the colored background), but not the ability to easily manage the drawing of shapes from WordPress. And also I don't believe that plugins like *WP Maps Pro*, offer the possibility to enter calendar events.

The ideal would be a mix of the two above.

What would be the solution?

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you can integrate WordPress event calendar plugins with custom maps that allow you to draw different areas. While many event calendar plugins come with built-in Google Maps integration, if you want more flexibility and control over the map features, you might need to use a combination of plugins.

Here's a general approach you can follow:

Choose an Event Calendar Plugin:
Start by selecting an event calendar plugin that suits your needs. Plugins like "The Events Calendar" or "Events Manager" are popular choices. Install and activate the plugin.

Choose a Custom Maps Plugin:
If you want to draw custom areas on your map, you can consider using a custom maps plugin like "WP Google Maps" or "Wp Maps Pro." Install and activate the custom maps plugin.

Integration:
Depending on the plugins you've chosen, there might be specific integration options or add-ons available to connect your event calendar with the custom maps.

Some event calendar plugins may have built-in compatibility with specific custom maps plugins. Check the documentation or support forums for your chosen event calendar plugin.

Alternatively, you might need to write custom code or use a third-party add-on if direct integration is not available. This might involve creating a custom template or using hooks provided by the plugins.

Custom Template or Code:
If the integration is not direct, you may need to create a custom template for displaying events that includes the custom map. This could involve using shortcodes provided by the plugins or using PHP functions to fetch and display events alongside the map.

php
Copy code
// Example: Display events and map using "The Events Calendar" and "WP Google Maps" shortcodes
echo do_shortcode('[tribe_events]');
echo do_shortcode('[wpgmza id="1"]');

Styling and Configuration:
Customize the appearance and configuration of both the event calendar and the custom map to ensure they align with your website's design and functionality requirements.

Remember to check the documentation and support resources for the specific plugins you're using. If there's a lack of direct integration, you might consider reaching out to the plugin developers or community for guidance. Additionally, be sure to test the integration thoroughly to ensure that it meets your expectations and works smoothly on your website.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that use of AI Tools (e.g., ChatGPT) to generate or reword content that you post [is not permitted](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831) on Stack Overflow, even if you vet this content beforehand. Also see the related [Help](/help/ai-policy) on this topic. We do hope you'll stick around and become a valuable member of the community by contributing your own quality answers and questions in the future!

Comment: This is poorly formatted [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (or similar) output.